# How to remove the other APEX report download format?

Tags: oracle-apex

I created an interactive report in apex, and in actions there's a download feature. Is there any way to remove the other report download format like html, email, and PDF. I want to retain th csv file format only.

Answer (score 2):

Select the interactive grid, Click Attributes, Go to the Download section and check or uncheck the options you want to remove.

[image]

Comment: I'm not using interactive grid, I only use the interactive report and when I changed it to interactive grid, I cannot find the attributes,

Comment: Here's only what I see https://github.com/Feyifey/github-slideshow/issues/2

Answer (score 0):

Yes..You can do the same in Region attributes, based on your requirement you can do that in Intractive report.

[image]

Comment: Thank youuuu, I found it!